# How to enable /arch:AVX for Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4, avx, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to setup AVX support for Unreal Engine 4. It is using SSE2 by default as far as I know and it's own NMake so there are no Visual Studio properties page to access and add arch to.

Where am I supposed to set this up?

**NOTE**: Trying to support AVX, AVX2 and AVX512.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the VSToolChain.cs file in the UE4 source code. That file is setting up all the compiler flags for MSVC.

In there, search for where it's doing /arch:AVX. It's in some if(). To force usage of AVX or AVX2 or AVX512, just put /arch:AVX or /arch:AVX2 or /arch:AVX512 at the top of that function so that the flag always gets added. Then recompile the engine.